# How merge the overlapping sticker with image in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, merge, uiimageview, uiimage

i am trying to merge two different images in single image and trying to save it in the photo gallery. But the sticker which i am trying to merge on the image is getting stretched and not properly align to x and y in the image.

the code i am using is as below:

```
- (UIImage*)buildImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);

    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    CGFloat scale = image.size.width / _workingView.width;
    NSLog(@"%f",scale);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale);
    [_workingView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *tmp = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return tmp;
}
```

here in this code _workingview is the view containing the sticker image inside it & image in the arguement is the main image which we are passing in the function

[image: as you can see the image width is replace with image height]

i would be very much thank full for your help

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

CGFloat width, height;

```
CGFloat width, height;
UIImage *inputImage;    // input image to be composited over new image as example

// create a new bitmap image context at the device resolution (retina/non-retina)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), YES, 0.0);        

// get context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       

// push context to make it current 
// (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);                             

// drawing code comes here- look at CGContext reference
// for available operations
// this example draws the inputImage into the context
[inputImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
 [stickerImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(yourX,yourY,othertWidth,otherHeight)]

// pop context 
UIGraphicsPopContext();                             

// get a UIImage from the image context- enjoy!!!
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// clean up drawing environment
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```